# HP 3500yl-48G not giving PoE for Linksys SPA942

Tags: hp, power-over-ethernet

What can I have configured bad, when PoE on HP 3500yl-48G isn't working?

The IP phone, Linksys SPA942, works at another PoE switch.

Port configuration:

- PoE Enabled: `Yes`
- Maximum Watts: `17`
- Priority: `low`
- Allovation: `usage`
- LLDP

  - Dot3 LLDP TLV: `Enabled`
  - PoE LLDP-MED: `Disabled`
- Configuration type: *empty*
- Threshold: `80`

Statistics:

- Detection status: Searching...

[image: configuration screenshot]

[image: my setup connected]

Answer (score 1):

Both HP 3500yl-48G-PoE+ & Linksys SPA942 supports 802.3af PoE standard and the power consumption should only be aroung 5 Watts, so your configuration seems compatible.

HP Linksys SPA942 IP phone supports LLDP-MED (*Media Endpoint Discovery*, an enhancement of LLDP) for its PoE management. However, currently your port 23 has PoE LLDP-MED disabled. I'd try enabling LLDP-MED.

Comment: Thank you for edit and answer. As suggested I tried to change LLDP to TLV on, MED off; TLV off MED on; both on; both off, but none of this combination helped to solve the problem...